# Create random binary string: how to remove null character '\0' from to_string() before inserting to another string

Tags: c++, string, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to create a random binary string that consists of 0s and 1s. In my implementation i generate random integers 0s and 1s, and then I use std::to_string() in order to typecast them to a string and insert them into another string. The problem that I have is that it seems that by using std::to_string() in order to insert '0' or '1' characters, I also insert the terminating null character '\n' and therefore I double the size of the string. So for example, say I want to create a string consisting of Nbits=10 characters. With the implementation below I get a 10 elements string as printed on screen, however the size of the string is double that. Do you know how I could avoid this?

The problem with the size is that I am trying to write a binary representation of a genetic algorithm, and I need the size to be the correct one for the crossover/mutation operators to be correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

std::random_device rd;    
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

// Random bit string generator 
string random_string(size_t Nbits){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> int1(0,1);
    string s;
    s.resize(Nbits);
    for(size_t i=0; i<Nbits; i++)
            s.insert(i,to_string(int1(gen)));

    return s;
};

int main(){
    // Say I want a 10 bits random binary string 
    size_t Nbits=10;
    string s=random_string(Nbits);

    // If I print my string on screen, it has the correct number of entries: 
    cout<<s<<endl;
    // However the size of the string is not equal to the number of entries. 
    cout<<  "Number of bits is: "<< Nbits<<", length of string is "<< s.size()<<endl;

}
```

Possible output:

```
1001111111
Number of bits is: 10, length of string is 20
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your insertion logic is converting values it doesn't need to. There is no reason to convert data for a string of bits where you already know the possible outcomes of each bit: `0` or `1`.

And `.insert()` is the wrong method. You're stacking data into a string that is already previously sized, thereby adding *more* chars, not replacing them. You should start with an empty string, then push data in, reserving if desired (but not required).

Try this:

```
std::string random_string(size_t Nbits)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> int1(0,1);
    string s;
    s.reserve(Nbits);
    for (size_t i=0; i<Nbits; i++)
        s.push_back(int1(gen) ? '1' : '0');
    return s;
};
```

---

Alternatively, exploit the fact that `'0'` and `'1'` are guaranteed to be contiguous values per the standard, and perhaps do something like this instead:

```
std::string random_str(size_t Nbits)
{
    std::string s;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(s), Nbits,
        std::bind(std::uniform_int_distribution<char>('0', '1'),std::ref(gen)));
    return s;
}
```

There are a multitude of ways to do this, just a few mentioned here. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `random_string` you create a string of `Nbits` characters, which means its size is `Nbits`. Then you *insert* characters, making the string longer.

There are two obvious solutions: One is to use `i` as an index into the string, and set that character. The other is to not set the size at all, and just append the new characters.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for creating a random binary string, would be to first create a random value:

```
  std::random_device rd;
  std::mt19937 gen(rd());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 20);
  int val = dis(gen);
```

Then pass this random value as input argument to the following number to binary string convertor:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_binary_string(T const &val) {
  return std::string(std::bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT>(val).template to_string<char,std::string::traits_type,std::string::allocator_type>());
}
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e3dc654c33c2561)